# Aggregate initialization with curly braces

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate, uniform-initialization

In C++11, are the aggregates allowed to be copied with curly-braces syntax? I have the following code:

```
struct s
{
    int x;
};
template<class T>
struct holder
{
    template<class A>
    holder(A&& x) : t{x} {}
    T t;
};
```

Each one of the statements below works.

```
auto s1 = s{1};
auto s2(s1);
auto s3{s1}; ///NOTE : this works!
```

However, the second statement below raises the error `cannot convert 's' to 'int' in initialization`.

```
holder<s> h{5};
holder<s> h1{s{5}};
```

I am using gcc 4.8.2. Why do I get this error?

Comment: This code with statement holder<s> h{5}; is compiled successfuly at www.ideone.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, when a type `T` is an aggregate type, initialisation using `{ ... }` performs aggregate initialisation. Aggregate initialisation always initialises the members of `T`, not `T` itself.

Although this is exactly what the standard requires, this is unwanted, which is why in a future standard, the rule will likely be changed to make a special exception for initialisation from the same type. [This is core language issue 1467.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467)

Until that time, unfortunately, the error you are getting is entirely correct, and you will have to work around it.

Comment: I know it is an issue with aggregate with curly braces initialization (also mentioned in TC++PL book errata), and will be corrected in C++14. However, as shown in the code, `auto s3{s1};` does work, while `holder<s> h1{s{5}};` or, `s s4{s1};` does not work. What could be the reason that the first one works?

Comment: @abir In `auto s3{s1};`, `auto` is deduced as `std::initializer_list<s>`, not as `s`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code

```
struct s
{
    int x;
};
template<class T>
struct holder
{
    template<class A>
    holder(A&& x) : t{x} {}
    T t;
};

int main() 
{
    holder<s> h{5};
    return 0;
}
```

is compiled successfuly.

The invalid statement is

```
holder<s> h1{s{5}};
```

The problem is that in fact you are trying to execute

```
s s1 = { s{5} };
```

However the compiler is unable to convert an object of type s to an object of type int (that to initialize s1.x) when it tries to make assignment

```
s.x = s{5};
```