# Why do I get error C2797 in this example?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initialization, uniform-initialization

I have the following code:

```
struct X
{
    int a, b;
};

class Y
{
public:
    Y(const X& x) : x_{x} {};  // C2797 error

private:
    X x_;
};
```

Compiled with MSVC2013 Update 3, it complains about a [C2797 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx). If I replace the curly braces with parantheses (i.e. `x_(x)`) the program compiles successfully.

Why does this happen? Is this compiler behaviour C++11-compliant? What about C++14?

**Edit:** To be more clear, I am not sure if `x_{x}` above should, according to the standard, call `X(std::initializer_list)` or if it's a valid syntax for calling `X(const X&)`. As far as I know, it is the latter. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. If you are implying that the answer is in there, I didn't understand it, and I'd appreciate it if you could point it out in an answer here.

Comment: @Dan: You are using list initialization `{}`, and doing so inside the member initializer list.  The error message is saying that's a legal thing to do, but the compiler isn't ready to let you do that.  Try `x_(x)` instead as a workaround, that's direct initialization, not list initialization.

Comment: @Ben: so if I understand correctly, are you saying that `{}` initialization would be legal, but it's just not implemented in this compiler?

Comment: @Dan: Yes.  More probably, the part of the compiler that decides whether it is legal in this particular case isn't implemented yet either.  Since your `struct X` is an aggregate, I would use braces `{}` for aggregate initialization (a special form of list-initialization), and `()` for copy construction, which is what you have here.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks. Please formulate this as a brief answer.

Comment: It seems that gcc complains as well: http://ideone.com/pbzNzm

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard:

> — If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed.
>
> [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

In the context above, `x_{x}` will not call the copy constructor, because `X` is an aggregate. It will attempt aggregate initialization, which:

- In MSVC, is not implemented. MSVC also seems to fail compilation when `X` is `std::string`, which is not an aggregate, so it may have some C++11 compliance issues.
- In gcc, it is implemented, but the program is ill-formed and cannot compile (attempting to initialize an aggregate expecting `{int, int}` from a `{const X}`.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, gcc *does* know what that syntax means, gives a specific error message:

```
cannot convert ‘const X’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

That's because curly braces `{}` trigger list-initialization, and list-initialization for an aggregate type (your `struct X` is an aggregate, if you don't know why, just think "like an array, it just holds stuff without any behavior of its own") performs aggregate initialization.  Aggregate initialization means that initializers get paired with data members in order, and any extra data members get value initialized.

`x_.a` is paired with `x`
`x_.b` is paired with nothing, so value initialized

That's not what you want, because you can't stick all of `x` into `x_.a` (which is what gcc tells you).  What you did want is direct initialization using the copy constructor, written as `_x(x)`.

The story in Visual C++ is a bit different.  Microsoft engineers are still working on adding in C++11 support, and this is one of the things they haven't finished yet (at least in your version).  The compiler knows that when it sees `{}` in a ctor initializer list, that means list-initialization, but it doesn't know how to do that, so it gives up.

In particular, it doesn't get to the point of seeing that `X` is an aggregate, pairing initializers with data members, and finding out whether pairing `x_.a` with `x` is possible.

When a compiler tells you "this is not implemented", it doesn't mean the code is good, it doesn't mean the code is bad.  It means compiling that code needed logic that isn't released yet (could be not yet written, could be not yet tested, no one outside Microsoft knows).  Your code got delivered to the factory, loaded on the conveyor belt, started moving down the assembly line, and... fell off the end of the belt, because the machine that deals with that kind of code isn't in the factory yet.  No one knows whether if the machine were there to pick it up, it would have dropped it in the error pile or gotten it on another conveyor.

Comment: I guess what's unclear to me is this: `x_{x}` is not list initialization, is it? According to uniform initialization rules, this syntax should be calling the (compiler-defined) copy constructor of `X`, i.e. `X(const X&)`, *not* `X(std::initializer_list)`. This part of the C++ language syntax is not being parsed correctly by either gcc or MSVC.

Comment: I added an edit to my question to clarify the answer I'm looking for.